# Polymer installation doesn't work

Tags: polymer

After downloading all all the components of Polymer, I can not install it via the command line. Can someone write all of the step by step procedures?. I have already visited the site to see how but this does not work.

I am using Windows 10 and the command line for installation.

Comment: Don't work is pretty generic. Do you get an error message? What steps did you take?

Comment: Polymer is largely a set of Javascript files to include in your website. What's there to "install"?!

Comment: 1) i follow the instructions of site of Polymer, but doesn't work.

Comment: 3) if you want answer to this question, contact me on Facebook, because i am new in Polymer's world. I need better instructions for know how install this. https://www.facebook.com/keepcalmevincelinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to start off with Polymer Starter Kit, which includes instructions for setup and build.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit

Comment: if you want answer to this question, contact me on Facebook, because i am new in Polymer's world. I need better instructions for know how install this. facebook.com/keepcalmevincelinter